# why Thread.currentThread.interrupt() combined with return can stop a current running thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Well, I am trying to understand why the following combination  of Thread.currentThread.interrupt() and return  is working fine, when I want to terminate a current thread.

```
Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
return;
```

I write a small program:

```
public class Interr implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i= 0; i<10000;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i==500){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return ;
            }
        }

    }   
    public static void main(String args []){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Interr());
        thread.run();
    }
}
```

I know I can also use Thread.currentThread.stop() but it is an unsafe way to terminate a thread. So I tried to use the combination interupt() and return.

It works but I do not undestand why it works.

Any Explanation?

Edit: in the above example, I am the owner of a Thread. Assume, I am not the owner of a thread. Why This combination is working?

Comment: Why not just `return`? Why even consider stop/interrupt?

Comment: I am justing trying to understand, how I can stop  a current running Thread safely in more complicated situations (here was the example to easy)

Comment: When the thread comes to an end, it will stop. In the simplest case when you return the thread will be stopped in a safe way, since it is not needed anymore.

Comment: assume I am not the owner of the Thread. I should use in this case the combination

Comment: Java threads don't have "owners".

Comment: A thread stops _itself_ by returning (as explained in several answers, below).  Threads do _not_ stop each other in any well-designed program.  Threads in a well designed program cooperate with one another.  One thread might _ask_ another to stop, in which case the other thread should recognize that it was asked, clean up whatever it needs to clean up, and then return.  `t.interrupt()` is a low-level mechanism that you can use in a protocol that one thread uses to notify another thread of some unusual request (e.g., a stop request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to call `interrupt()` from same thread.

interrupt method will be used to interrupt a thread from other thread.

as per java docs.

> Interrupts this thread. Unless the current thread is interrupting
>   itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess method of this
>   thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException to be thrown.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt
>   status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

So it will send interrupt signal to the thread which is in I/O block.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

    }
}
```

if a thread has implementation like that , it wont interrupt even after calling this method.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `interrupt()`. The `return` is enough to exit `run()` which will then cause the thread to stop, since it has no more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the code you posted the reason the thread stops is because you called `return`.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), calling `Thread.interrupt()` does nothing more than set a flag on the thread you're calling it on. The owner of the thread checks the flag and must find a way to stop what it is doing.